# How to find most top 3 menus in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to find most top 3 menus in lunch module.
Now I code like this

```py
import random

from odoo import api, fields, models, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError


class LunchOrderLineFavorite(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'lunch.order.line.favorite'

    menu_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='lunch.order.line', string='Menu', domain=lambda self: [("product_id", "in", self.env['lunch.order.line'].search([]).ids)])
    #.mapped("order_id")
    @api.multi
    def favorite_pick(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        print self.menu_ids.id


        order_line = self.env['lunch.order.line'].create({
            'product_id': self.menu_ids.id,
            'order_id': self._context['active_id']
        })
```

and got 2 problems
1. menu created but not match with I choose.
2. I don't know how to find top 3

Thanks,
regards.

Comment: You would like to know what is the product order the most time? Based in product_id ?

Comment: YES. I would to know that.